# Solution of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y\mathrm{e}^x$ given $x=0$, $y=\mathrm{e}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, exponential-function, absolute-value

> $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y\mathrm{e}^x$, $x=0$ and $y=\mathrm{e}$. Find the particular solution.

**Attempt 1**
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y\mathrm{e}^x\implies\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x\implies \log|y|=\mathrm{e}^x+C\\
x=0,\,y=\mathrm{e}\implies\log|\mathrm{e}|=\log\mathrm{e}=1=1+C\implies C=0\\
\log|y|=\mathrm{e}^x\implies|y|=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x}\implies \color{red}{y=\pm\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x}}
$$
**Attempt 2**
$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y\mathrm{e}^x\implies\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}=\mathrm{e}^x\,\mathrm{d}x\implies \mathrm{e}^x=\log|y|+\log|C_1|=\log|C_1y|\\
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x}=|C_1y|=\pm C_1y=Cy\\
x=0,\,y=\mathrm{e}\implies\mathrm{e}=C\mathrm{e}\implies C=1\\
\implies \color{red}{y=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x}}
$$

My reference also gives the solution $\log y=\mathrm{e}^x$ as in attempt 2. Why do I seem to get positive and negatve solutions in attempt 1 ?

How do I eliminate the solution $y=-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^x}$ in attempt 1 ?

**Note:** I am not quite familiar with the idea of singularity or intermediate value theorem, as i have only done preliminary maths on first order differential equations.

Comment: FWIW, $e^x > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. EDIT: nevermind, that means you could have $y<0$ for your attempt 1.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe : Or go right where previously it was wrong. The sign of $y$ has to be constant, as $y=0$ is a constant solution, thus no crossing the zero-line. The sign of the solution is decided by the sign of the initial value, $y(x)=y(0)e^{\exp(x)-1}$, this was not used in the first attempt.

Comment: I do not see what in this step is wrong. Removing the absolute value introduces a sign, the sign can be absorbed into the constant.

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe how do the step $|C_1y|=\pm C_1y=Cy$ be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt is incomplete. You got to the point where two solutions $y(x)=e^{e^x}$ and $y(x)=-e^{e^x}$ are possible. The sign can not change inside a solution as they never take the value zero but have to be continuous. A sign change would thus contradict the intermediate value theorem.

As $y(0)=e>0$, you can reduce the number of possible solutions to one.

Comment: Thnx. but I am not quite familiar with intermediate value theorem. Is it possible to understand eliminating the solution $y=-e^{e^x}$ if have only basic knowledge about first order differential equations ?

Comment: Look at the initial condition. Does it satisfy $y(0)=e$?

Comment: A continuous function on $[a,b]$ takes any value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. This is the basic property of continuous functions. Any solution that has $y(x_0)=0$ somewhere is the zero solution everywhere by the uniqueness theorem.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with the integral

$$\int \frac{dy}y=\log|y|+C$$ you are not allowed to cross the singularity at $y=0$ so that the solution is more precisely one of

$$\log y=e^x+C\text{ or }\log(-y)=e^x+C$$ (for all $x$).

With the given initial condition, the second option is excluded.

Comment: $\log|y|=e^x\implies \log y=e^x$ or $\log -y=e^x$. How does the condition $x=0,y=e$ decides the second option is excluded ?. Can I understand it if i have only basic knowledge on differential equations ?